# How does the Scala compiler decide it needs to provide for a match error?

Tags: java, scala, switch-statement

The Java compiler requires a Default Case even when it seems obvious all cases are accounted for. e.g.,

```
    public static int ternCollatz(int n) {
        switch (n % 3) {
            case 0: return n / 3;
            case -2:
            case 1: return 2 * n + 1;
            case -1:
            case 2: return -2 * n + 1;
        }
    } // Won't compile, "missing return statement"
```

In Scala, one can be oblivious to missing cases until runtime.

```
  def ternCollatz(n: Int): Int = n % 3 match {
    case 0 => n / 3
    case 1 => 2 * n + 1
    case 2 => -2 * n + 1
  }
```

Test this with a negative number like −38 and JUnit will quite correctly report `scala.MatchError: -2 (of class java.lang.Integer)`. Last night, I tried a few different versions of `ternCollatz()` and I should have paid attention to which version I called Javap on. I believe the following was for a working version; I noticed the `MatchError` instantiation on line 63:

```
public int ternCollatz(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iconst_3
       2: irem
       3: istore_2
       4: iload_2
       5: tableswitch   { // -2 to 2
                    -2: 46
                    -1: 54
                     0: 40
                     1: 46
                     2: 54
               default: 63
          }
      40: iload_1
      41: iconst_3
      42: idiv
      43: goto          75
      46: iconst_2
      47: ... omitting a few lines ...
      59: iadd
      60: goto          75
      63: new           #251               // class scala/MatchError
      66: dup
      67: iload_2
      68: invokestatic  #61 
          // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljav
                                                      /lang/Integer;
      71: invokespecial #254 
           // Method scala/MatchError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      74: athrow
      75: ireturn
```

I thought this was because I rewrote one case to use an Or, or maybe because it's missing some special annotation. Today, that I come back to this, and from this version of `ternCollatz()`

```
  // NO ANNOTATION
  def ternCollatz(n: Int): Int = n % 3 match {
    case 0 => n / 3
    case -2 | 1 => 2 * n + 1
    case _ => -2 * n + 1
  }
```

I get the following from Javap:

```
  public int ternCollatz(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iconst_3
       2: irem
       3: istore_2
       4: iload_2
       5: tableswitch   { // -2 to 1
                    -2: 42
                    -1: 50
                     0: 36
                     1: 42
               default: 50
          }
      36: iload_1
      37: iconst_3
      38: idiv
      39: goto          59
      42: iconst_2
      43: iload_1
      44: imul
      45: iconst_1
      46: iadd
      47: goto          59
      50: bipush        -2
      52: iload_1
      53: imul
      54: iconst_1
      55: iadd
      56: goto          59
      59: ireturn
```

No `MatchError`. This is what I wanted. But I'd like to know how is it that the the Scala compiler knew there's no need for a `MatchError` here? Is the special annotation ever absolutely necessary or is it just a convenience to not need to pore over Javap?

---

Side question: why is it necessary for line 56 to `goto` line 59? Couldn't `ireturn` be on 56 and 39 and 47 be changed accordingly?

Comment: There's no match error because the last case `case _` covers every single case. It's the Scala equivalent of `default`

Comment: @user So then I was probably using `case -1 | 2` instead for the version I used Javap on...